# How to get typed value from RECORD type in Avro?

Tags: java, avro

I am working with Avro and I have a `GenericRecord`. I want to extract `dataTimestamp`, `processTimestamp`, `clientId`, `processId` and `deviceId` from `goldenHeader` value.

```
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "goldenHeader",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "GoldenHeader",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "dataTimestamp",
        "type" : "long"
      }, {
        "name" : "processTimestamp",
        "type" : "long"
      }, {
        "name" : "clientId",
        "type" : "int"
      }, {
        "name" : "processId",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "string",
          "avro.java.string" : "String"
        } ]
      }, {
        "name" : "deviceId",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "avro.java.string" : "String"
        }
      } ]
    },
    "doc" : "Golden header"
  },
  .. some other fields
  ]
```

My `GenericRecord` looks like this when we get the data:

```
{"goldenHeader": {"dataTimestamp": 1481055083500, "processTimestamp": 1481055085524, "clientId": 1234, "processId": null, "deviceId": "ducer"}}
```

Now I am confuse how can I extract individual fields from `goldenHeader` which is a `RECORD` type. When I print out the class name for `goldenHeader` I see this:

```
org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record
```

Below is the code I have got but I am confuse what do to next:

```
  public static Object fromAvro(Object obj, Schema schema) {
    if (obj == null) {
      return null;
    }
    System.out.println(schema.getType());
    switch (schema.getType()) {
      case RECORD:
        // not sure what to do here
    }
  }
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your object actually has those fields on it, its runtime class is some subclass, you just need to find out what class it actually is. Easiest way in my opinion is `instanceof`:

```
public static Object fromAvro(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null) {
    return null;
  }

  if(obj instanceof MyClass) {
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass)obj;
    GoldenHeader goldenHeader = myClass.getGoldenHeader();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Well I don't have any pojo stuff here. So I need to manually extract it somehow.

Comment: Do you mean when you do `obj.getClass()` it returns `java.lang.Object`? Then I am not sure you are actually passing the data into Java.